# Node of ScyllaDB is giving Connection Refused, in Docker

Tags: scala, scylla

I'm new to ScyllaDB. I have locally installed ScyllaDB and running container using:

```
 docker run --name Node_X -d scylladb/scylla --overprovisioned 1 --smp 1
```

Then I'm making more two Nodes of same cluster using:

```
docker run --name Node_Y -d scylladb/scylla --seeds="$(docker inspect --format='{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' Node_X)" --overprovisioned 1 --smp 1
```

```
docker run --name Node_Z -d scylladb/scylla --seeds="$(docker inspect --format='{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' Node_X)" --overprovisioned 1 --smp 1
```

The problem is, Node_X and Node_Y are running properly:

```
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address     Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  172.17.0.3  440 KB     256          ?       0e061c1c-20d7-43e3-8e8f-2133e9589a95  rack1
UN  172.17.0.2  208 KB     256          ?       02c639ba-05ed-4ff5-bf3b-8e1358c6c0cf  rack1
```

But Node_Z is not working, and giving error:

```
nodetool: Unable to connect to Scylla API server: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
See 'nodetool help' or 'nodetool help <command>'.
```

In logs of Node_Z, error is:

```
FATAL: Exception during startup, aborting: std::runtime_error (Could not setup Async I/O: Resource temporarily unavailable. The most common cause is not enough request capacity in /proc/sys/fs/aio-max-nr. Try increasing that number or reducing the amount of logical CPUs available for your application)
2023-03-22 11:02:27,583 INFO exited: scylla (exit status 7; not expected)
2023-03-22 11:02:28,584 INFO gave up: scylla entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
```

I've seen one solution to increase (aio-max-nr) but I'm not able edit that. Please help in that, how can I make three nodes cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Node_Z is giving the Connection Refused issue, just go into the Node_Z using:

```
docker exec -it Node_Z bash
```

Then after entering into bash, change aio-max-nr using:

```
sudo sysctl fs.aio-max-nr=1048576
```

It will change that number, you can check using:

```
cat /proc/sys/fs/aio-max-nr
```

Now exit from bash. Stop that container and remove it. Now you can make more conatiners/nodes.